# Alternative option of UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvents: method in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know that this question has been asked so many times but i want to pass a custom object as an argument on clicking a button.

`UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` doesn't allow us to do that but it is important for me so I can do further on the basis of custom objects.

If an alternative for add target is possible, so please give the solution.

The code is like this:

Custom Object:

```
HeaderData *cell ;
```

Button:

```
_forward =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[_forward setTitle:@"F" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_forward.frame = CGRectMake(300, (_CELL_HEIGHT-_LABEL_HEIGHT)/2, 10 ,_LABEL_HEIGHT);]
[_forward addTarget:web action:@selector(functionName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the function which is called on clicking the UIButton _forward is:

```
-(void)functionName:(UIButton *)sender{
    //code for further programming on the basis of cell.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a custom subclass of UIButton:

```
@interface CustomDataButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, strong) id userData;
@end
```

Then in functionName, you can pull the data back out:

```
-(void)functionName:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[CustomDataButton class]])
    {
        id customData = ((CustomDataButton *) sender).userData;
    }
}
```

**caveat**: written without an IDE. Watch out for typos etc.